# Javascript for loop architecture for Html Rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large array file containing 10 top objects. Each of them has 10-100 children and each child has 10-100 elelment.

The way i process it now if a triple for loop looping through 2000 objects and building html for those objects and appending it to the page.

```
$('body').append(generatedHTML);
```

The problem i am facing now is that the rendering takes forever, and while this is being processed the page freezes.

Is there a better way to implement such solution? Like for example Loading this a step at a time so the user can still interact with the page while its being loaded?

Example code below

```
for (var i = 0; i < rootElements; i++) {
  var child = rootElements[i];

  var new_obj = child.secondElement;
  for (var j = 0; j < new_obj.length; j++) {
  // Another for loop to process the children of new_obj
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like infinite scrolling?

Comment: Do you absolutely want to have all of the items on the page at once?

Comment: Maybe use a framework that handles MVC? Or maybe you are doing something in the for loop that is very costly?

Comment: that much markup alone can be slow no matter how it's generated or loaded. i would do some pagination.

Comment: Yes I am looking for something like infinite scrolling, but on the client side, I have no control over the API serving the data, and sometimes the data can reach 3-4 MB

Comment: Without knowing what you are doing exactly it is really impossible to help you. Only thing is if you want to do infinite scrolling that loop partially, remember where you left off and continue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `setTimeout()` to delay loading stuff.
Also you could take a look at this:
http://www.javascriptkata.com/2010/08/10/nofreeze-a-library-that-avoids-freezing-in-javascript/

Comment: I will look at that library and make sure to mark the answer as correct once i test it. Thank you Fabius